# ${\left( {\overline {A \cap B} } \right)^{\text{o}}} = A \cap B$ and $A \subseteq B \Leftrightarrow \bar A \subseteq \bar B$

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question:

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A,B \subseteq X$ such that ${\left( {\bar A} \right)^{\text{o}}} = A{\text{ }}$  and ${\left( {\bar B} \right)^{\text{o}}} = B$. 
> Prove that:
>
> (i) ${\left( {\overline {A \cap B} } \right)^{\text{o}}} = A \cap B$
>
> (ii) $A \subseteq B \Leftrightarrow \bar A \subseteq \bar B$
>
> $Note:{\text{ Here (}} \cdot {{\text{)}}^{\text{o}}}{\text{ is the interior operator and }}\overline {( \cdot )} {\text{ is the closure operator}}{\text{.}}$

My work so far:

**(i)** 

$\begin{gathered}
  A \cap B = {\left( {\bar A} \right)^{\text{o}}} \cap {\left( {\bar B} \right)^{\text{o}}} = {\left( {\bar A \cap \bar B} \right)^{\text{o}}} \supseteq {\left( {\overline {A \cap B} } \right)^{\text{o}}} \hfill \\
  \therefore {\left( {\overline {A \cap B} } \right)^{\text{o}}} \subseteq A \cap B \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

 How can I show the reverse inclusion?

**(ii)** $A \subseteq B \Rightarrow \bar A \subseteq \bar B$ is easy to establish, I'm struggling mostly with the converse ($\bar A \subseteq \bar B \Rightarrow A \subseteq B$). 

 If I start with $\bar A \subseteq \bar B \Rightarrow \overline {{{\left( {\bar A} \right)}^{\text{o}}}}  \subseteq \overline {{{\left( {\bar B} \right)}^{\text{o}}}}$, how should this reducte to $A \subseteq B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i)

$A$ and $B$ are interiors of sets, hence are open sets.

Then also $A\cap B$ is an open set,
and this with $A\cap B\subseteq\overline{A\cap B}$.

This implies
that $A\cap B\subseteq\left(\overline{A\cap B}\right)^{\circ}$

---

(ii)

From $\overline{A}\subseteq\overline{B}$ it follows directly that
$\left(\overline{A}\right)^{\circ}\subseteq\left(\overline{B}\right)^{\circ}$
which in this context is the same as $A\subseteq B$.